# Linear Damping of charged particles in a constant magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, material-science

I am an undergraduate mathematician working on a problem which involves two identical charged particles in a constant external magnetic field (directed orthogonally to the plane that the particles lie in).

I studied a little bit of electrodynamics in order to derive a Lagrangian for the system:

$$L = \frac12 m( ||\dot{q_1}||^2 + ||\dot{q_2}||^2) + \frac{e}{c}(A(q_1) \cdot \dot{q_1} + A(q_2) \cdot \dot{q_2}) - \frac{\alpha}{||q_1 - q_2||}$$

Where $q_i$ is the position vector of particle $i$, $A$ is the magnetic vector potential, and $m, c, e, \alpha$ are constants.

I wanted to consider a 'medium', or perhaps some external force, that would act as a velocity-dependent linear damping (like friction). Making the Euler-Lagrange equation(s) of the form:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}} = \gamma \dot{q_i}$$

For some damping coefficient $\gamma$.

Though I am primarily interested in controlling the dynamics of the system, I also would like this to be a physically permissible (if not relevant) situation. Do such resistive mediums/forces occur in electrodynamics?

I hope this question is well-posed enough. Let me know if there is anything unclear or simply wrong about what I am saying/asking.

Comment: It seems like this is an active research topic you are looking at.    https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6309   I don't know if that article helps. But it looks like you are doing something at least superficially similar.

Comment: @puppetsock: The connection was unintential, but indeed is relevant. My question is more directed at the possibility of *existence* of damping in this system rather than the formulation of the Lagrangian. Though now there is another problem at hand, lol

Comment: If the Lagrangian term is $A(q)q$, it represents action of an electric field. To include effect of magnetic field, one would have to use Lagrangian term of type $A(q)\dot{q}$ (magnetic force depends on velocity).

Comment: @JanLalinsky ah yes, that is a mistake. It has been fixed, thanks